# How can I count the number of elements that match a predicate with Streams?

Tags: java, java-8

In Java7 I have this code:

```
public int getPlayersOnline() {
    int count = 0;
    for (Player player : players) {
        if (player.isActive()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I'm trying to use Java 8 features as much as possible, how can I go about improving this with lambdas?

Comment: Is `players` an arraylist of `Player`?

Comment: Please accept the answer below if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This would be a one-liner:

```
return (int) players.stream().filter(Player::isActive).count();
```

Comment: Nice answer. Can you also share any good tutorial(link) to learn about using lamda expression in java 8?

Comment: @Andreas done so. But the problem here is that there are many links without nice explanation. Anyways, will see if I get something useful to share or may be write a blog about it later on

Comment: Check out the Oracle Youtube Videos

Comment: @Balwinder Singh: If you don’t know where to start, why not the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html#javase8)?

Comment: Isn't a downcast from long to int dangerous? How can I count the elements without downcasting to int?

Comment: You can only do it by returning a long, which the OP did not do.  But frankly it's not particularly dangerous; a `Collection` is at most int-sized, and this is a filter of a `Collection`.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between this and the OP's Java 7 version?